# How to change the system path of a taxonomy vocabulary to correspond a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm using Drupal 8 and i want different vocabularies to be displayed by different views. 
Each view should have a different path with a contextual filter but when i define my path on pathauto the alias will be pointed to the system path.

I know there's modules that solve this like Taxonomy Display and Entity Path but because i'm using version 8 i really can't afford these modules.

Can you help me to change the default system path of each taxonomy vocabulary to correspond to a custom view?

Thank you for reading

Comment: Hm, I don't understand your problem. Can you maybe add some samples of what you mean exactly? You have to define the paths inside the view (if it's a views page) or (if it's a block) define the alias of the page you want to place the block at.

Comment: Apart from that there's the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module which let's you configure to always redirect to the alias path.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for the answer. My path has contextual filters like /collection/[collection:title] and brand/[brand:title]. Each one of these paths has a different view wich will override the default taxonomy view taxonomy/term/%. Path auto doesn't set alias to the views i created instead it defines a path for the default taxonomy view taxonomy/term/%.

The only way to do this is to change the system path manually. I would like to know if there's a way to do it massivelly in order to change the system path of all the alias of a specific vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem installing the module: Taxonomy Views Integrator -  https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi.

It's easy to set a view to display both taxonomy terms and vocabularies.